# Update Locale Value by URL (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, localization

I have a project written in Laravel. I use multiple languages with Laravel Localization.

It works fine, but when I visit the URL directly, the content is not updated.

For example, if I visit this URL directly, the content language does not change: site.com/en/slug-url

But if I change the language with changeLanguage and then visit the same url, the content comes in English.

If the locale value is *en*, how can I translate the site to English by running the changeLanguage function at the same time?

**Controller**

```
  public function changeLanguage($locale)
    {
        // Check supported languages
        $supportedLocales = ['en','tr'];
       
        // If it is a supported language, update your language preference
        if (in_array($locale, $supportedLocales)) {
            session(['locale' => $locale]);
            App::setLocale($locale);
            
        }

        Artisan::call('view:clear');
        Artisan::call('route:clear');
        LSCache::purgeAll();

        // You can perform other actions or redirect
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```

**Routes**

```
      /* Lang */
        $router->get('/lang/{locale}', 'HomeController@changeLanguage')->name('change_language');
```

Also if I visit **site.com/en** the language does not change. But if I visit **site.com/lang/en** the language changes.

I couldn't find a solution

Answer (score -2):

You need a middleware to check the locale of a `URL` and change de site locale. You can follow [this tutorial](https://lokalise.com/blog/laravel-localization-step-by-step/) to set localization properly.